# Polymorphism Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and have question .
After running this code ,the result displayed is

"Name is Bob and salary is50000 and work is main.PizzaRobot object at 0x00000000028EECC0>>"

I want "work" to be displayed for each object in **str** rather than calling obj.work() for each object .

In this problem output should be "Name is Bob and salary is50000 and work is Bob makes pizza"

Thanks

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self,name,salary = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
    def giveraise(self,percent):
        self.salary = self.salary + self.salary * percent
    def __str__(self):
        return "Name is {0} and salary is{1} and work is {2}".format(self.name,self.salary,self.work)
    def work(self):
        print(self.name ,"does stuff")

class chef(Employee):
     def __init__(self,name):
         Employee.__init__(self,name,50000)
     def work(self):
         print(self.name ,"makes food")

class PizzaRobot(chef):
     def __init__(self,name):
         chef.__init__(self,name)
     def work(self):
         print(self.name ,"makes pizza")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bob = PizzaRobot("Bob")
    print(bob)
```

Comment: you should use `super().__init__(name,50000)` and give each class an occupation attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.work` is a function, thus your behaviour.

In the `work` functions, instead of doing a print, use return:

```
 def work(self):
     return self.name + " makes food")
```

And then, you can use

```
return "Name is {0} and salary is{1} and work is {2}".format(self.name,self.salary,self.work())
```

(note the `()` at the end, `self.work()`. You will call the function)